# Proof of $ind(\underline X) = 0 \Rightarrow Ind(\underline X) = 0$ if $\underline X$ is $T_1$ with a countable basis.

Tags: general-topology

In H. Herrlich's *Topologie I* book there is a proof of the fact that if $\underline X$ is $T_1$ and has a countable basis, then it holds that $\operatorname{ind}(\underline X) = 0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{Ind}(\underline X) = 0$.

- Here $\underline X$ is said to have $\operatorname{ind}(\underline X) = 0$ if it has a basis $\mathscr{B}$ consisting of clopen sets.
- Whereas $\operatorname{Ind}(\underline X) = 0$ if for any neighborhood $U_A$ of some closed set $A$ there is a clopen set $B$ in $\underline X$, such that $A \subset B \subset U_A$.

---

The author starts by defining:

$$C = \{ B \in  \mathscr{B} \ | \ B \subset U  \}$$
$$D = \{ B \in  \mathscr{B} \ | \ B \subset X \setminus A \}$$

Then proceeds to state that $C$ and $D$ can be written as:

$$C = \{ C_n \ | \ n \in N\}$$
$$D = \{ D_n \ | \ n \in N\}$$

Then also defines:

$$E_n = C_n \setminus \bigcup\{D_m \ | \ m \le n\}$$
$$F_n = D_n \setminus \bigcup\{C_m \ | \ m \lt n\}$$
$$E = \bigcup \{ E_n \ | \ n \in N\}$$
$$F = \bigcup \{ F_n \ | \ n \in N\}$$

Saying that $E$ and $F$ are open sets in $\underline X$ with $F = X \setminus E$.

He then concludes with the fact that $E$ is therefore a clopen set with $A \subset E \subset U$ and thus it holds that $\operatorname{Ind}(\underline X) = 0$. $\blacksquare$

---

I have a difficulty understanding how the author rewrites $C$ and $D$ as:

$$C = \{ C_n \ | \ n \in N\}$$
$$D = \{ D_n \ | \ n \in N\}$$

such that he can later conclude $F = X \setminus E$. While I get that they can be represented as countable sets and thus as some sequences of sets, I can't understand how one goes to the conclusion from that. Especially what $E_n$ and $F_n$, $E$, $F$ are supposed to represent. Seems to me that it's somehow about the area formed by $U \setminus A$.

Does anyone have an idea and could explain the steps in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewriting is a pure formality for notational reasons: $\mathcal{B}$ is countable (given) so $\mathcal{C} = \{B \in \mathcal{B}: B \subseteq U\}$ is also a countable family of clopen sets (being a subfamily of $\mathcal{B}$) so we fix some enumeration of it and write it as $\{C_n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. The same applies to $\mathcal{D} = \{B \in \mathcal{B}\mid B \subseteq X\setminus A\}$ which we can write as $\{D_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. Having these indices makes it easy to define

$$E_n = C_n \setminus \bigcup \{D_m \mid m \le n\}$$

and $$F_n = D_n \setminus \bigcup \{C_m \mid m < n\}$$

which is a standard way (in other proofs this also occurs) to "disjointify" a family of sets.

If we just took the union of the $C_n$ as given, that union would be just $U$ because of the fact that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$, so $U$ as an open set is exactly a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$ and we take all such $C_n$. Likewise, the union of all $D_n$ is just $X\setminus A$, which is also open. So these unions would intersect exactly in the gap $U\setminus A$.

A nice thing about the definition of the $E_n$ and $F_n$ is their (almost) symmetry: and the fact that we can use that all finite unions of clopen sets are clopen and their difference is also clopen, so all $E_n$ and $F_n$ are still clopen, like the $C_n$ and $D_n$.

Let's check that $E \cap F = \emptyset$:

Suppose $x \in E \cap F$. Define $n_0 = \min \{n\mid x \in E_n\}$ and
$m_0 = \min \{m \mid x \in F_m\}$. So $x \in E_{n_0}$, so $x \in C_{n_0}$ and $x \notin \bigcup_{m \le n_0} D_m$ which implies $m_0 > n_0$. On the other hand we have $x \in F_{m_0}$, so $x \in D_{m_0}$ and $x \notin \bigcup_{m < m_0} C_m$ which in turn implies $n_0 \ge m_0$. We cannot have both $m_0 > n_0$ and $n_0 \ge m_0$ so this cannot happen.

Also, $X = E \cup F$: if $x \in A$, $x \in U$ so $x \in C_m$ for some $m$ and $x$ is not in *any* $D_n$ as these are all disjoint from $A$, so $x \in E_m \subseteq E$ is immediate. Similarly we get that $x \notin U$ implies $x \in X\setminus A$ so $x \in D_m$ for some $m$ and in no $C_n$ (as these sit inside $U$) and hence $x \in F_m \subseteq F$ for such $m$. The interesting case is when $x \in U\setminus A$ when we can again define $n_0=\min \{n\mid x \in C_n\}$ and $m_0=\min \{m\mid x\in D_m\}$. Now, If $m_0 > n_0$ we have that $x \in C_{n_0}$ but $x \notin D_m$ for any $m \le n_0$ (or that would contradict minimality of $m_0$) and so $x \in E_{n_0} \subseteq E$. If however $m_0 \le n_0$, we have that $x \in D_{m_0}$ but $x \notin C_m$ for any $m < n_0$ (or we'd contradict minimality of $n_0$), so $x \in F_{m_0} \subseteq F$.

So in all cases $E \cup F = X$ and so $E,F$ are clopen and it's easy to see that $A \subseteq E \subseteq U$. So $\operatorname{Ind}(X) = 0$.

Comment: What confuses me is that disjointification is usually done like this: $M_n = H_n \setminus \bigcup \{H_m \ | \ m \lt n\}$. I.e from any $H_n$ we subtract all previous ones but not like what we see here as $E_n$ and $F_n$. 
Regarding the last point, I don't get why $T_1$ and such basis imply that $E$ and $F$ are complements.

Comment: @СССР Here we don't make the *family* of $E_n$ and $F_n$ pairwise disjoint  among themelves (which we could also do) but we make them mutually disjoint in their *union*. Hence the slightly different but similar approach.

Comment: After your explanation I've also drawn a picture and now I get it. $E_n$ and $F_n$ complement each other inside $U \setminus A$. Outside of it, they, of course, do not affect each other.

Comment: Does this prove it?

$x\in U\setminus A \Rightarrow \exists B \in \mathcal B, x \in B \subset U \Rightarrow  \exists n \in N: x \in C_n$.

Let $n = min(\{n \in N: x \in C_n\})$.

If $x \in E_n\Rightarrow x \in E \Rightarrow x \in E \bigcup F$.

Otherwise, $\exists m \le n: x \in C_n \bigcap D_m \Rightarrow x \in D_m$. Where $m$ chosen as smallest if there are multiple ones.

Therefore, $x \in F_m$, since $\not \exists n' \lt m \le n$ to allow $x \in C_{n'}$ ($n$ - was chosen smallest).

From this follows $x \in F\bigcup E$.

Comment: In my understanding if $m = n_0$ it isn't a problem because $D_m$ will contain $x$ while any $C_{n'}$ with a smaller index will not, since $n_0$ was chosen as the smallest index, so any index smaller will give us $C_{n'}$ which doesn't contain $x$.
This will imply that $x$ is not excluded by the union in $F_m$ and so belongs to $F_m$ and thus to $F$.

Comment: @СССР I redid the proof better and now it all checks out. I also removed the irrelevant comments.

Comment: One more note. Seems like the $T_1$ property here is not used. *H. Herrlich* uses it later in the same paragraph to show equivalence between above statement and others.

Comment: @СССР it’s needed to go from Ind to ind using points are closed sets. The $T_1$ is the overall assumption to make the full equivalence true.